# Javascript - Extract all Title from inner HTML of a DIV

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing

How to extract particular properties from inner HTML in a complete div.

For Ex - 
I have

```
[Check the image, I have highlighted the part I want to extract][1]
```

I want to extract only the last 5 digits number from every ALT="Blah, blah... , 87876 " inside the blue highlighted div

After that i want to put all the values in an array with comma seperated and remove all duplicates.

```
      var Array = [];

    // solution code

        var values = Array.join(", ");

    alert (values);

// shows up "34322, 23215, 52334, ....., 34123"
```

Please explain with an example respective to my problem mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Your picture didn't show up, but it's easy enough to get the number:

```
var example = "Blah, blah... , 87876 ";
example.trim().match(/[\d]+$/g)
```

You can use `querySelectorAll` to get all elements with an `alt` attribute:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content *[alt]')
```

Combine these ideas with `Array.reduce` and you can build a list of all the numbers:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content *[alt]')).reduce((acc, el) => {
   const match = el.getAttribute('alt').trim().match(/[\d]+$/g);
   if (match) { return acc.concat(match); }
   return acc;
}, []);
```

Here is a non-es6 version:

```
var elements = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content *[alt]'), 0);
elements.reduce(function(acc, el) {
   const match = el.getAttribute('alt').trim().match(/[\d]+$/g);
   if (match) { return acc.concat(match); }
   return acc;
}, []);
```

Removing duplicates is easy with es6:

```
const altNums = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content *[alt]')).reduce((acc, el) => {
   const match = el.getAttribute('alt').trim().match(/[\d]+$/g);
   if (match) { return acc.concat(match); }
   return acc;
}, []);
const unique = [...new Set(altNums)];
```

Comment: Here is the image - http://imgur.com/a/gb9kB

<div class="tab-content"> all the ALT attributes are inside this div

Can you please edit the code and add this class to get all the ALT and remove duplicates.

Comment: But how do i get all values in a variable as comma seperated
For ex -
**var xyz = "12321, 23123, 23423, .......,34245"**

Comment: `altNums.join(",")` will build a comma-separated string from the array

Comment: I am using it in imacros and it says document is not defined.

Comment: @ Piyush Verma : You can use another selector query to replace the `document` portion of `altNums` variable above, e.g: `document.querySelector('.tab-content').querySelectorAll('[alt]')` This will return all child elements of 'div.tab-content' which contain an 'alt' attribute.  To return a comma-separated string from an array use `Array.join(',')` - See MDN here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: @RobM. I am using it in imacros addon for firefox and it says document is not defined.
I have created a .js file and copied the code and it returns that error

Comment: You should tag your question with `imacros`, the answer I posted is how you would accomplish this with vanilla Javascript - I have no idea about the external constraints that imacros puts on this task.